# If we have a increasing sequence of nonnegative functions, does $\liminf \int f_n = \int f$ imply that $\lim \int f_n =\int f$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I am doing a practice problem from measure theory and I am trying to prove that we can prove the monotone convergence theorem assuming Fatou's lemma is true. In most proofs I have seen, the final step is just showing that $\int f$ is greater than the limsup and less than the liminf of the sequence of integrals which would imply that $\lim \int f_n =\int f$. Now for what I did, my final step was that $\liminf \int f_n \leq \int f \leq \liminf \int f_n $ which implies $\liminf \int f_n =\int f$ and I said that implies $\lim \int f_n =\int f$. Is that wrong? In the case of sequence, that is generally not true, but in this specific case, we have that $f_n$ is a increasing sequence of nonnegative functions, so for any fixed $n$, we have $\inf \int f_j$ for $j \geq n$ is actually just $\int f_n$ so taking the limit $n \to \infty$, we have $\liminf \int f_n=\lim \int f_n$. Is that correct?

Comment: Each $f_n$ is an increasing function or $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$? Your wording does not agree with what you are saying later.

Comment: ''sequence of nonnegative increasing functions''and 'increasing sequence of  nonnegative functions' are two different things.

Comment: thank you. i have made some edits.

Comment: $(\int f_n)$ is itself an increasing sequence, so its $\lim, \lim \sup, \lim\inf$ are all the same.

Comment: @geetha290krm ok thank you